# Convert IF/AND to VBA and extend to sheet

Tags: excel

I have a spread sheet which is used for basic scheduling of tasks.

Dates for the calendar run along Row 1 from O-NO and everything below is job related including due dates.

I am trying to automatically add a note to the calendar section of the sheet when a date is added to column E.  The word “Due Date” is update to the corresponding text row/date column.

Colum E = due dates, Columns O to NO (rows are infinite) are days Jan – Dec.  I have created the cell formula =IF((AND($E452=$1:$1)),"Due Date","") which is cell specific.

I need to keep the cells clear of formulas because they are used for adding other details so a Macro is the way to go.

I thought I could convert the formula to a macro and then manipulate the code to do what I need across all of the calendar cells.  Below is the result.

```
Sub DueDate()
'
' DueDate Macro
'

'
    Range("IM451").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((AND(RC5=R1)),""Due Date"","""")"
    Range("IM452").Select
End Sub
```

Firstly I tried a number of ways just to get this macro to run automatically without having to manually run it. For some reason I couldn’t get it to work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
MACRO CODE HERE
End If
End Sub
```

Plus a couple of other versions

Second step was to get it to work across all of the calender cells, another fail.
Would really appreciate some assistance on this.
Thank you

CRB

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 5 Then
        Set c = Range(Cells(Target.Row, "N"), Cells(Target.Row, "NO")).Find("Due Date")
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.ClearContents
        Set c = Nothing
        If IsDate(Target.Value) Then
            Set c = Range("N1:NO1").Find(Target.Value)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then Cells(Target.Row, c.Column).Value = "Due Date"
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

When a date is entered in column E, this will look for that date in range `N1:NO1`, and if the date is found, will insert "Due Date" in the matching column of the target row.

Comment: Might be worth turning off events as you're changing the value of cells within the code which will cause the code to fire again.

Comment: Yeah - will cause very little performance impact in this case, but you're right that it's good practice to include. Have edited.

Comment: Thanks Olly (& Darren), appreciate the help.  Your interpretation of my description was correct.  I have tried the code in the actual sheet and a blank sheet and there is no Due Date output. Set c = Range(Cells(Target.Row, "N"), Cells(Target.Row, "NO")).Find("Due Date")
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.ClearContents
        Set c = Nothing

Comment: Forget the above...rewritten...   Thanks Olly (& Darren), appreciate the help.  Your interpretation of my description was correct.  I have tried the code in the actual workbook and a blank workbook and there is no Due Date output.  In the code there is Find ("Due Date") and then the next line ClearContents.  Is this just part of the code going through  each cell in the specified area?

Comment: @Olly , could you please double check the code.  I cannot get any output, I have tried a clean workbook with no success. Thankyou.

Comment: O.K got it so the code should actually go into the “Sheet” window not the “ThisWorkbook” or module.  Thank you